# No menu in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I wonder why I don't see the menu on the top of the page (File Edit ... Help). I have just updated it from 2.9.4 to 2.10.2. Is there something I can do to make the menu appear?
As a non computer expert, I have already tried to

- move the mouse everywhere,
- Clic right and look for some option to activate/desactivate,
- Restart the computer.

[image]

It runs on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / GNOME Flashback.

Comment: I guess you'd get more answers at http://askubuntu.com/, because it's a technical problem with the editor or the desktop environment, not a question about TeX.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I copied the question there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/687711/no-menu-in-texstudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Qt 5. See http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1512/